# JPA/Hibernate not storing @MapKeyColumn's value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dictionary, key

I have a bi-di Map mapping.
Reading works, but Hibernate doesn't store the map key column.
When I check in debugger, everything is set as it should.

The INSERT query is:

```
insert into rel_custField (field_id, release_id, value, id) values (22, 1, 'fwefwe', 3)
```

It should also contain set the `name` column. ***How should I achieve that?***

Maybe the problem is that the map item entity doesn't have the `name` property? But I have never seen in docs/spec that it should.
If I opted for that solution, I'd have to manually set the name property which seems impractical and redundant.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity @Table(name="`release`")
public class Release implements Serializable, IHasTraits {

    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "release", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    //@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "release_id") // Only at one side.
    private Map<String, ReleaseCustomField> customFields = new HashMap();

    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rel_custField", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "rel_prodcf", columnNames = {"release_id", "field_id"})
})
public class ReleaseCustomField implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    private Long id;

    // Make uni-dir?
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "release_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Release release;

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description I found here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Map_Key_Columns_.28JPA_2.0.29

it should not be a property of the target entity, but a column name. E.g.:

```
@MapKeyColumn(name = "id")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "release", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
private Map<String, ReleaseCustomField> customFields = new HashMap();
```